# Connecting HTTPS API with TLS 1.2/1.3 connection in Android 2.3.3 (Gingerbread) API 10

Tags: android, ssl, tls1.2, android-2.3-gingerbread

Firstly I have found same question but it 5 years old and its not helping me so i am asking one more time.

I have android API 10 which i am working. I have to make API call to may server that server running HTTPS with TLS 1.1/1.2 protocol connection.

Can any one point me to some right direction. from where I can begin on. Or any third Party library name that can help me to connect my server with Android API 10, That would be nice.

Please Help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time sorry forget to answer my Question.

I have found solution in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` File. Server side I have edit `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file and add `cipher suite` which available in my custom android OS for making TLS 1.0 connection. I have add `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` cipher suite on my server and working.

Answer (score 1):

TLS 1.1/1.2 support started with API 16 , so you can only use 1.0 with your target API.

Source : https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html

Comment: When i use TLS1.0. java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SSLContext TLSv1.0 implementation not found.

Comment: yes that what I am saying, I can make TLS1.0 call from API 10 which is not default but as par Android doc it is available from API 1. But still i can make call using TLS1.0 and it's say you dont have that protocol  implementation in your device.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Volley Lib Click [Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Comment: Same thing with Volley lib. javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x21ecf8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

Answer (score 0):

You could use [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library

Comment: Retrofit can only deserialize HTTP bodies into OkHttp's ResponseBody type and it can only accept. Same response from OkHttp lib.